# How to remove the box frame in "plot.raster" in R package "raster"

Tags: r, plot, spatial, raster

I need to remove the box frame around the figure in R package "raster", but I cannot figure out which argument I should change. The example is as follows:

```
library(raster)

r <- raster(nrows=10, ncols=10)

r <- setValues(r, 1:ncell(r))

plot(r)

plot(r,axes=F)
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This works:

```
plot(r, axes=FALSE, box=FALSE)
```

To learn how you could have found that out for yourself, have a look at the underlying functions by trying the following. (The calls to `showMethods()` and `getMethod()` are needed because the **raster** package makes extensive use of S4 methods rather than the more commonly used S3 methods.)

```
showMethods("plot")
getMethod("plot", c("Raster", "ANY"))
getAnywhere(".plotraster2")
getAnywhere(".rasterImagePlot")
args(raster:::.rasterImagePlot)
# function (x, col, add = FALSE, legend = TRUE, horizontal = FALSE, 
#     legend.shrink = 0.5, legend.width = 0.6, legend.mar = ifelse(horizontal, 
#         3.1, 5.1), legend.lab = NULL, graphics.reset = FALSE, 
#     bigplot = NULL, smallplot = NULL, legend.only = FALSE, lab.breaks = NULL, 
#     axis.args = NULL, legend.args = NULL, interpolate = FALSE, 
#     box = TRUE, breaks = NULL, zlim = NULL, zlimcol = NULL, fun = NULL, 
#     asp, colNA = NA, ...)
```

Comment: This is fantastic. Thanks

Comment: @gonzalez.ivan90 You bet. Glad it helped.

Comment: plot(r,box=F) does not give error but still plots the box.

Answer (score 1):

The best I can suggest is

```
plot(r,axes=F,useRaster=F)
```

The option `bty='n'` usually gets rid of the box, but the raster-plotting function seems to be drawing its own box on top of the regular box that you can't get rid of.