# R - plot raster without box

Tags: r, raster

I have a problem getting rid of the box when plotting raster with colour scale:

```
require(raster)
data(volcano)
raster <- raster(volcano)

colfunc <- colorRampPalette(c("blue", "red"))
plot(raster, col = colfunc(40), breaks = seq(minValue(raster), maxValue(raster), length.out = 40), bty = "n", xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n")
```

the `bty` option simply doesn't work. Am I missing something here?

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/q/14469753/684229

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it:

```
plot(raster, ..., bty="n", box=FALSE)
```

It is interesting that both `bty="n"` and `box=FALSE` must be set! If you try only one of these, the box will be printed!

Comment: This bizarrely doesn't work for me. Does for the example but not my RasterLayer object

Comment: @geotheory ha, interesting! It seems that you need to set both `bty="n"` and `box=FALSE`! Maybe you were just setting `box=FALSE`? Updated my answer.

Comment: Bonus question - any idea how to suppress the axis lines and tick marks but not the labels?

Comment: @geotheory I don't know but try to suppress the axes and use the axis command to customize them. If you fail post a new question.